# Creating a function that runs arbitrary shell commands in Go

Tags: bash, shell, go

I am trying to create a generic function in go that takes in input a shell command (with arguments) and execute it.

Note the shell commands may have a different number of arguments.

I understand that the `exec.Command()` in Go takes as input the format `("ls", "-la", "/var")` for the command + arguments.

This code snipped below doesn't work:

```
func exe_cmd(commandarray []string) {
var shell_command string = ""
for i := 0; i < len(commandarray); i++ {
                  shell_command = shell_command + " " + commandarray[i]
                  }
cmd := exec.Command(shell_command)
fmt.Println("Command is: ", shell_command)
fmt.Printf("==> Executing: %s\n", strings.Join(cmd.Args, " "))
out, err := cmd.Output()
fmt.Printf("OutVar: %s\n", out)
fmt.Printf("ErrVar: %s\n", err)
}

func dummy() {
dummycmd := []string{"ls", "-la", "/var"}
exe_cmd(dummycmd)
}
```

A the end of the `for` the `shell_command` variable will contain `"ls -la /var"` and I am having a hard time to figure out how to form it in a way that is what the input format requires i.e. `"ls", "-la", "/var"`

I have also tried to set `dummycmd` as a variable with `"ls -la /var"` but I figure that was even worse if requirement is to pass it to the exec.Command in the format above.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply match the argument signature of the `exec.Command` function, which is

```
(name string, arg ...string)
```

And use the variadic syntax to pass the function argument along to `exec.Command`

```
func execCmd(name string, args ...string) {
    cmd := exec.Command(name, args...)

    fmt.Printf("Command is: %s, %s", name, args)

    out, err := cmd.Output()

    fmt.Printf("OutVar: %s\n", out)
    fmt.Printf("ErrVar: %s\n", err)
}
```

Note however, you're not invoking a shell here, so relying on any shell builtin's will fail.

Comment: Thanks @JimB Mh... I am not sure I am following. I am trying to pass an array for args (which is what I was trying to do before including the actual command as first argument) but it complains that `cannot use shell_commandArgs (type []string) as type string in argument to exec.Command`.

Comment: Maybe I have misinterpreted what you were suggesting. Now I have created a string variable that contains `ls` and another string variable (not a slice) that contains `-la /var`. This works better and it executes but for some reasons it is misinterpreted (it exits 1 instead of listing the content of `/var`). With one argument only (e.g. `-la` it works just fine.

Comment: Every argument is separate. The full string `"-la /var"` isn't a valid argument to `ls` -- you want `"-la", "/var"`.

Comment: Yes. agreed. That is part of the problem I am trying to solve. I am trying to build a generic function that can accept a variable number of arguments. I originally thought I could pass a slice that contains all the individual arguments and inside the function I'd concatenate them properly to pass them onto the exec.Command instruction.

Comment: @mreferre: You don't concatenate them, you can do just what I've shown here to pass any number of arguments. The `exec_cmd` function accepts a variadic number of arguments, and passes them all along to `exec.Command`.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Silly me that I went down the road of building an array to then decompose it and then concatenate again when I could have done something like: `exe_cmd("ls", "-la", "/var")`. What confused me is that I didn't know that a Go function could accept a variable number of parameters (sorry, I am 6 hours into Go) :) Thanks a lot. Seems to be working now.